# Langchain Ouput Parser on QA Chain

Tags: python, langchain

How does one correctly parse data from load_qa_chain?

It is easy to retrieve an answer using the QA chain, but we want the LLM to return two answers, which then parsed by a output parser, PydanticOutputParser.

The chain returns:

```
{'output_text': '\n1. Contract item of interest: Termination. \n2. Termination: Yes.}
```

But then trying to parse the result with the parser gives JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) :

```
parser.parse(result['output_text'])
```

How should I change the chain to be able to correctly parse the output?

Here is the chain below:

```
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

from langchain import PromptTemplate
from dotenv import load_dotenv


from langchain.output_parsers import PydanticOutputParser
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
import os

from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader

load_dotenv()

def load_embeddings(row_num):
    """
    This function loads embeddings from source documents. We want to answer questions from 
    these documents.
    """
    embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings(
        openai_api_key=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
        deployment=os.getenv('EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME'),
        model=os.getenv('EMBEDDING_MODEL'),
        chunk_size=1
        ) 
    
    loader = CSVLoader(file_path='data/contacts.csv', source_column="Context", csv_args = {"delimiter": ',',})

    doc = loader.load()
    contract = [doc[row_num].page_content]
  
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size = 500,
    chunk_overlap  = 50,
    length_function = len,
    )
    
    context_split = text_splitter.create_documents(contract)
    
    db = Chroma.from_documents(context_split, embedding_function)
   
    return db

row_num = 0
db = load_embeddings(row_num)
item = "Termination Clause" # The item we want to search for

class PersonIntel(BaseModel):
    contract_item_of_interest: str = Field(description="Item that is being searched for in the contract")
    item: str = Field(description="Is there any evidence that of the item in the contract? Yes or No")

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "contract_item_of_interest": self.contract_item_of_interest,
            "item": self.item,
        }

llm = AzureOpenAI(deployment_name=os.getenv('CHAT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME'), 
                    openai_api_version="2023-05-15",
                    model_name=os.getenv('CHAT_MODEL'), 
                    temperature=0)

query = f"Is there any evidence that of {item} in the contract?"

docs = db.similarity_search(query)

template = """
You are a legal assistant. Given the following contract below, Answer the question. 
Questions: 
1. Can you tell me whether {question} is mentioned in this contract? 

{context}

# Your answer must be returned in the following structure:
1. Contract item of interest: {question}. 
2. {question}: Yes or No'. 
\n{format_instructions}
"""

parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=PersonIntel)

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=template, 
    input_variables=["summaries", "question"], 
    partial_variables={
        "format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions()
    }
)

chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff", prompt=PROMPT, document_variable_name="summaries")
result = chain({"input_documents": docs, "question": item}, return_only_outputs=True)
result
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that content of `result[output_text]` is invalid JSON. The input to `parser` must be a correctly formatted JSON string in the format

```json
{
    "contract_item_of_interest": "...",
    "item": "..."
}
```

For example, this code works perfectly fine,

```
parser.parse('{ "contract_item_of_interest": "value1", "item": "value2" }')
```

returning `PersonIntel(contract_item_of_interest='value1', item='value2')`.

Make sure to very clearly and precisely instruct the LLM to output JSON in the correct format. Giving it an example of a valid JSON object also helps.

Change the last line in `template` to be something along the lines of:

```
Your answer must be a JSON string with the following keys: 

"contract_item_of_interest", "item"

Here is an example of the JSON output expected of you:

{
    "contract_item_of_interest": "value1",
    "item": "value2"
}

Make sure to output only the JSON object and nothing else.
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to manually type out the JSON in the instructions, you could use `parser.get_format_instructions()`. See instructions [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/output_parsers/types/pydantic).